# Fallback text if no results in Google Charts API

Tags: google-visualization, googlevis

I am unable to find the right function from the google charts (Google Visualization API) that would set the text/message to be shown if no data is supplied to it/data supplied does not yield a chart(eg: all y values 0)

Comment: You could code some simple javascript to go through each data value and validate the chart data beforehand. This would likely be much easier. I am not aware of any native function in Google Charts API that does that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://modernizr.com/
try with the svg fallback ;)
if the browser doesn't support SVG you may can show an update message or convert the JSON to a table.